# "Unexpected end of file" error: What am I missing?

Tags: php

OK....Thank you for all who chimed in--you are why I love this site. The error was me uploading the wrong file with a different name. HOWEVER--PART 2--while I got rid of the unexpected ending error, I also now get a like 7 rows of 9 columns of INPUT fields (text boxes that say 
"

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","XXXX","XXXX");
if (!$con){
die("can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("i541280_wp1",$con);


if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE wp_usermeta SET bio='$_POST[bioupdate]'WHERE
author_bio='$_POST[hidden]'";
mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);

};

$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta";
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
echo "<form action=bio.php method=post>";
echo "<input type=textarea name=bio value=" . $record['bio'];
echo "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['bio'];
echo "<input type=submit name=update value=update";
echo "</form>";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: remove `;` after closing curly bracket of your second if condition..

Comment: @NishantSolanki: No, you may add as much `;` as you want w/o syntax errors. That's an empty statement.

Comment: OK....Thank you for all who chimed in--you are why I love this site. The error was me uploading the wrong file with a different name. HOWEVER--PART 2--while I got rid of the unexpected ending error, I also now get a like 7 rows of 9 columns of INPUT fields (text boxes that say 
"<input". I was expecting 1 textarea and a submit button. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE wp_usermeta SET bio='$_POST[bioupdate]'WHERE author_bio='$_POST[hidden]'";
```

It should be this; note the proper single quotes for the `$_POST` keys as well as a space before `WHERE`. I have also formatted it for clarity/readability with one item per line:

```
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE wp_usermeta"
             . " SET bio='" . $_POST['bioupdate'] . "'"
             . " WHERE author_bio='" . $_POST['hidden'] . "'"
             ;
```

Also, this is wrong:

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    // Removing code for clarity.
};
```

Remove that extra `;` at the end to make it like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    // Removing code for clarity.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the `\n` in the string of `$UpdateQuery` is causing this:

your code

```
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE wp_usermeta SET bio='$_POST[bioupdate]'WHERE
author_bio='$_POST[hidden]'";
```

Better:

```
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE wp_usermeta SET bio='" . 
                  $_POST[bioupdate] . 
                  "'WHERE author_bio='$_POST[hidden]'";
```

Multiline Strings are depending on what version of PHP you have.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ; from If condition 
and change the query

```
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE wp_usermeta SET bio='".$_POST[bioupdate]."'WHERE
author_bio='".$_POST[hidden]."'";
```